# How to get csv file in request in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to get csv file in post(request) in django.

```
file = request.FILES['file'] # is this way is correct to get csv file
```

I have tried code above but getting this error:

```
UnsupportedMediaType: Unsupported media type "text/csv" in request.
```

Please help I am stuck for two days now.

```
def post(self, request, version_id):
    """
    upload csv file to s3
    params: request (csv file)
    """
    response = {"success": True, "data": {}, "message": ""}
    file = request.FILES['file'] #is this way is correct to get csv file
    is_valid, message = self.validate_file(file) #this function for check file is csv or not
    if is_valid:
        ImageUpload = ImageUploader()
        try:
            response = ImageUpload.upload_file(file)
        except Exception as e:
            response.update({"success": False, "message": e})    
    else:
        response.update({"message": message, "success": False})
    return Response(response, 200)
```

Comment: You must be using a ```form```. Please post HTML code as well.

Comment: @Ram I want to upload a CSV file to s3(AWS) so first fetch the file csv and uploaded function works properly if I am running direct function given with file path but when I  using request.FILES , so getting error

Comment: How are you uploading ? There must be some web-page where you upload/fill data. Post that HTML Code.

Comment: @Ram someone else working on HTML. I am a newly backend developer. the task is upload a csv file from frontend(dashboard). and receive that file and direct upload on s3 server. that is task and frontend task doing another person.

Comment: Try printing out ```request.FILES``` and see it if has the file you are looking for. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) for more info.